# Eclipse Code Corrupted after Crash

Tags: eclipse, corrupt

I closed Eclipse because I had a feeling my PC was gonna crash (been acting funny today), and it said it saved my workspace and closed normally.

But when I went back in after reboot, my workspace wasn't loading - even after selecting the right one my projects wouldn't show and the layout was reverted to default....not such a big deal, just re-imported.

But... One of the source files I was working on seems to have been corrupted, replaced with one continuous line of squares, which is kind of a big deal :/

Any thoughts on what caused this? I know there's probably no chance of getting that file back, but if anyone has had a similar experience or knows what the jaysus happened that'd be cool! Ideally I'd like if this never happened again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was related to my SSD: Weird bug where after 5184 hours of use it would shutdown.

Firmware update fixes the problem.

More here: http://www.tomshardware.com/news/Crucial-m4-Firmware-BSOD,14544.html